# Is it possible to restrict a VBA macro command to just one workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have macros added as commands to a specific workbook. But a new workbook will show the commands, and if I click it, it just opens the previous workbook. I would rather them not be there in new workbook's command bar. Is this possible?

Comment: Where exactly are these macros installed?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure. When I insert module, it doesn't give me option where to save.

Comment: _Where_ do you insert the module?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I go to Developer tab > VB > Insert > Module.

Comment: To clarify, in bold at the top of the Project window, it says VBAProject (Filename.xlsm)--not (Personal.xlsb)

Comment: And that is where you save the module: Filename.xlsm, they will appear as long as that file is open.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad ok didn't know they'll appear and disappear in a new workbook depending on whether that one is open. I guess my question is specifically regarding the macro commands now (will edit to clarify).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Excel.Window)
  'This runs on switching to the workbook from another Workbook
  CommandBars("MyToolbar").Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
  'This runs on switching away from the workbook to another Workbook
  CommandBars("MyToolbar").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).